# BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset crash

Tags: java, android, crash, andengine

i have took a look to andengine a few months ago, and i managed to make something out of it.
Now i downloaded the newest version, and i'm having a crash for the simplest thing. Here my code

```
package francesco.mygame;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ColorBackground;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;



public class mainMenu extends BaseGameActivity 
{

// ===========================================================

// Constants

// ===========================================================
static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;

static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 320;



//private static final String TAG = "Main Menu";


// ===========================================================

// Fields

// ===========================================================

protected Camera mCamera;  
protected BitmapTextureAtlas mTexture;
protected TextureRegion mPlayTexture;
protected Sprite mPlaySprite;
protected Sprite mQuitSprite;
protected TextureRegion mQuitTexture;
protected Scene mMainScene;

// ===========================================================

// Constructors

// ===========================================================



// ===========================================================

// Getter &amp; Setter

// ===========================================================



// ===========================================================

// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces

// ===========================================================



@Override

public void onLoadComplete() 
{

// TODO Auto-generated method stub


}



@Override

public Engine onLoadEngine() 
{

    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera));

}



@Override

public void onLoadResources() 
{
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    this.mTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(64, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.mPlayTexture = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "play.png", 0, 0);
    this.mQuitTexture = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "quit.png", 0, 40);

    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);

}



@Override

public Scene onLoadScene() 
{

    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    this.mMainScene = new Scene();
    this.mMainScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

    int play_x = (CAMERA_WIDTH + this.mPlayTexture.getWidth() )/2 ;
    int play_y = (CAMERA_HEIGHT + this.mPlayTexture.getHeight())/2 - this.mPlayTexture.getHeight();
    this.mPlaySprite = new Sprite( play_x, play_y, this.mPlayTexture);

    int quit_x = (CAMERA_WIDTH + this.mQuitTexture.getWidth() )/2 ;
    int quit_y = (CAMERA_HEIGHT + this.mQuitTexture.getHeight())/2 + this.mQuitTexture.getHeight();
    this.mQuitSprite = new Sprite(quit_x, quit_y, this.mQuitTexture);

    this.mMainScene.attachChild(mPlaySprite);
    this.mMainScene.attachChild(mQuitSprite);

    return this.mMainScene;

}



// ===========================================================

// Methods

// ===========================================================



// ===========================================================

// Inner and Anonymous Classes

// =========================================================== 

}
```

(Usually it is well indented)

The logCat error is

Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitMapTextureAtlasSource. Asset path: gfx/play.png

java.io.FileNoFoundException: gfx/play.png

But i put the 2 images in the folder and i added them to the project like i did when i first tried andengine(and it worked)..
So i don't really understand where the problem is..

The images are 2 png created with the gimp(one is 57x36 and the other 58x31).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `java.io.FileNoFoundException` will be thrown if a file wasn't found - so there is no other possibility than the engine couldn't found the image.

Make sure your images are in: `assets/gfx/` and not just in a folder called `gfx/`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure there is assets folder in your project and from **BuildPath** options(project options-you can access by right-click on your project explorer), from Source Tab press Add Folder button and check assets folder to import your compilation process.

`gfx`folder must be in assets folder. If there is no such folder and all your images is assets folder, you don't have to set `BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/")`

I am new to android and if I gain errors I try possibilities rapidly to find correct one.